# jquery modal not getting selected value from asp drop down list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using [jquery simple modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).

```
function showCancelledModal() {
    $('#<%=CancelledPanel.ClientID %>').modal({ appendTo: 'form' });
}

<asp:Panel ID="CancelledPanel" runat="server" Style="display: none">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="CancelledDropDownList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClick="CancelButton_Click" />
</asp:Panel>

protected void CancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var item = CancelledDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value;
   //CancelReservation(strReservationId); 
}
```

The problem is, on my button click event it doesn't seem to get the selected value of the drop down list. It just defaults to the first value every time. I am binding the drop down list to a table in the page load event.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: After you rebind your DDL, it resets the selectedItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to post a single comment (maybe because I'm new here and have no reputation!).
So, here it goes...
This is pretty basic, but are you sure you're not databinding the dropdownlist on every single postback?

ie. Forgetting something like this:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        CancelledDropDownList.DataBind(); // this method will reset the SelectedValue
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Its been ages since I had this noob problem! But yes, I was rebinding the ddl on every postback.